# SELECT a value multiple time in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a code in PHP where I want to display multiple times values, and so, even if these values are the same between them. My code is simple :

```
$sql = "SELECT photo from table WHERE username IN ('1','2','2') ORDER BY id DESC ";

$res = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($res, $row['photo']);
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

But this code only display (in json) an array of two values (because the values of `photo` of the username 2 are the same).
What I want to achieve is to make an array with the exact same number of values of the number of username I defined `WHERE username IN ('1','2','2')` (so here, 3 values).
I hope you understood me, thanks for helping me !

Comment: Where are the values 1, 2, and 2 coming from? Are they user-supplied or do you know them in advance? Are they always the same?

Comment: the values are stored in database, these values can be anything, depending on what is in that database. (in fact in my real database this is not numbers but real username with profile picture URL, but I simplified the code)

Comment: You say that you are only working with one table so do the usernames (1, 2, 2 in your example) come from the same table? If not I think you simply need to join on the photo table when you are selecting the usernames. Can you show us the SQL you are using to get the usernames?

Comment: yeah if you want  an show you an exemple of the database. Moreover, I don't know in advance the value of username. Here I choose 1 and 2 for the example, but it can be 'hello' or 'Jean'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is to list even the duplicates in the end result.  As your SQL will only retrieve the unique items, the idea would be to include the username in the SQL result set.  Then use the original list of user names (`$userNames`) and add in the photo for each of them.

I've used `mysqli_fetch_all()` to simplify the process of fetching all of the data, then used `array_column()` to make the username the key for the photos.

```
$userNames = array(1,2,2);
$sql = "SELECT username, photo 
          from table 
          WHERE username IN ('".implode("','", $userNames)."') 
          ORDER BY id DESC ";

$res = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$photos = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$photos = array_column($photos, "photo", "username");
foreach ( $userNames as $user ) {
    if ( isset($photos[$user])) {
        $res[] = $photos[$user];
    }
    else    {
        $res[] = '';
    }
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems that I get an error with this code, It says that my usernames are undefined indexes.

Comment: Can you add `print_r($photos);` before the `foreach()`.  Can you also check the SQL has the right column names.

Comment: okay, I've added this, and the result is Array ( [0] => goodvalue.jpg )

Comment: Can you make sure the select has both these columns - `username, photo `.  I've also updated the code to set it to '' if there isn't a value for it.

Comment: okay, it seems to work, I'll validate your answer, just wait until I put it into my entire code, thanks man

Comment: Okay thanks man, even if I still have a problem (that I'll post when I will be able to do it), you answer correctly to the problem ! Thanks a lot, I hope this will help other people ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `left join`:

```
select t.photo
from (select '1' as username union all select '2' union all select '3'
     ) u left join
     table t
     on t.username = u.username
order by t.id desc;
```

Note this will return rows, even when the user name does not exist.  If you want to filter those rows, remove the `left` so you are doing an inner join.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a problem, I heard that LEFT JOIN is for linking two table, but here, I work with only one table.

Comment: It should be "select '1' as username union all select '2' union all select '2' " and also inner join as you said.

Comment: @error.exe . . . I don't understand your comment.  This query uses a derived table for the first "table" in the `left join`.